# Laptop utterly frozen on purple screen during boot

Tags: boot

Please remove 'duplicate'; solutions in linked question did not help.

I've happily been living off other people's processing power by just plugging my Ubuntu-install-on-a-stick in their computers, but there's one machine that just does not want to cooperate: my partner's laptop.

Simply put, immediately after I have selected an option in the GRUB boot manager, the screen just goes purple and the computer no longer responds. I have to shut down the machine by pressing the power button.

The machine is an HP Envy laptop, it has UEFI and is only a few years old. There is no dedicated graphics card, just an Intel Integrated chip. The computer runs Windows 10 and does that just fine.

Tried solutions as of 31 August 2017:

- Certain key strokes at the time of the purple screen: the computer seems to have completely stopped responding; nothing happens when pressing F4, F8, Ctrl+Alt+F2, Ctrl+Alt+Del or even the SysRq keys (the latter normally work even during boot). I don't expect anything to work as soon as this purple screen shows up.
- Recovery Mode, previous kernel version 4.10.0.28 instead of 4.10.0.32, adding kernel parameters `nomodeset` or `nolapic`.
- Waiting for 15 minutes
- Using a Live USB stick instead of a full install.
- Disabling Secure Boot.
- Booting in Legacy mode.

I have not tried all possible combinations of the above attempts (e.g. I did not wait 15 minutes for every new kernel parameter), let me know if there is a good reason to.

Any further ideas as to what might be wrong, or even just how I could somehow get diagnostic information about what causes the crash? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: Will try, but what previous kernel then? It's not like it used to work in the past.

Comment: Any of the previous kernels that you have there. The one you could boot.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks, I have tried most of the solutions in that post but will try the other kernel parameters once I get access to the machine.

Comment: If the remaining solutions you haven't tried yet don't help, you can **[edit]** your question with full details on everything you've tried and what happened; your edit will get it automatically reviewed for reopening.